# vim split buffer and have it open at the bottom

Tags: vim

```
:sp
```

opens up a split buffer on the top by default.

How do I give the split command so that the new buffer is opened up as the "bottom" buffer right away? (I don't want to do a C-w-r which I am aware rotates the buffer so that my newly opened buffer gets rotated to the bottom)

Comment: I didn't know about C-w-r and that's solved my problem, thank you :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`:belowright split` will open the new window on the bottom regardless of whether or not you have `set splitbelow`.  Similarly, `:aboveleft split` will open the new window at the top regardless of the `'splitbelow'` setting.

Answer (score 36):

Add `set splitbelow` to your .vimrc.  Similarly there is an option `splitright` for vertical splits.

See `:help splitbelow` and `:help splitright` for more info.